# Xcode: TableView cell to create ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

I've recently started using Xcode and Beginner to creating apps. I've come across something I'd like to implement but research hasn't been quite clear/complicated to understand.

I have a TableView with Days of Week and also a segmentedControl that duplicates these days 3 times. I'm wondering how I'm able to get user click to take me to an alternative ViewController depending on which day it is and what segment of the segmentedController is selected without having to create 21 viewcontrollers in the storyboard.

I've used a ViewController and made an outlet to a tableView for this setup.

[image: TableView with segmentedController]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you tableview delegate method -> `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath`

```
you can simply write 
let vc = UIViewController()
/*
you can add informations here 
*/
present(vc, animated: true)
```

and inside this method you can use the `indexPath` to get the cell you've clicked

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAt(indexPath)
```

now you can get the information in this cell

Comment: This solution seems simple and within my understanding. I have created a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/qRaHsftd with my code, how would I implement this solution given I have used a tableView as an outlet?

Comment: you should implement the didSelectedRowAtIndexPath just like you implemented the cellForRowAtIndexPath method,

Comment: Awesome! Got it!

Comment: and since you've have the datasource `workout_days` you can get the day -> let day = workout_days[indexPath.row] in side `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath` now you get the data you've clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can have one viewcontroller which is basically a recipe for the viewcontroller you want to go to.

For example you want to show a viewcontroller with a label that states a combination of the number from the segmented control and the date which the user tapped on.

If you now create a ViewController which has a label in storyboard, the text on the label doesnt matter, you can use code to change the text to anything you would like.

In the tableviewcontroller you can use the didSelect delegate method of your tableview to present the viewcontroller and set the label to the values of the segmented control and the cell which is tapped.

I think you just need some more information about iOS and programming in general, therefore I suggest you watch the following iTunes U course:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-10-apps-with-swift/id1198467120
It has everything you need to know

Comment: Thanks. So in this recipe viewController, say I had a input field for the user to change a label, would this text only appear on the given day and segment they have chosen? Also would this store for that specific day/segment if they had chosen to go to another screen and come back?

Comment: No, if you use the regular way of presenting a viewcontroller and you go back the viewcontrollers information is 'lost', if you want to store data you should do it in another class, you should google for some more information about mvc (model view controller), its a design paradigm to help you seperate views and logic

Answer (score 0):

Create a detail view controller with two variables (Ex - dayName and selectedSegmentIndex). And in your current viewController "tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)" push detailsViewController with these details like this

```
let objViewController: DetailsViewController? = UIStoryboard.mainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as? DetailsViewController
    objViewController?.dayName = dayName
    objViewController?.selectedSegment = segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    navigationController?.pushViewController(objViewController ?? UIViewController(), animated: true)
```